# Get the words from a string in multiple divs using a for loop with jQuery or regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex, for-loop, html-lists

I am currently creating list on the fly with jQuery. The solution below is somewhat hacky I know, so I am wondering if its possible to stick it in a loop, so I can iterate through each div and create the list. Thanks for your help!!

```
         var text0 = $('#d0').text(); 
         var textArr0 = text0.split('*');

         var text1 = $('#d1').text(); 
         var textArr1 = text1.split('*');

         var text2 = $('#d2').text(); 
         var textArr2 = text2.split('*');

         $("#d0").html('<ul></ul>');
         $("#d1").html('<ul></ul>');
         $("#d2").html('<ul></ul>');


         $.each(textArr0, function (k, v) {
            $("#d0 ul").append('<li>' + '<a>' + v + '</a>' +  '</li>');
         });

         $.each(textArr1, function (k, v) {
            $("#d1 ul").append('<li>' + '<a>' + v + '</a>' +  '</li>');
         });

         $.each(textArr2, function (k, v) {
            $("#d2 ul").append('<li>' + '<a>' + v + '</a>' +  '</li>');
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tidied version of what you've already got...

```
$(function() {
    $("#d0, #d1, #d2").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var textArr = text.split("*");
        $(this).html("<ul></ul>");
        for(var i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
            $(this).find("ul").append('<li><a>' + textArr[i] + '</a></li>');
        };
    });
});
```

But, I'd recommend giving the elements d0/d1/d2 etc. a class and use `$(".className")` to identify them so you can have as many or as few as you like without having to change that code.

Here's a demo... http://jsfiddle.net/77vM9/

Comment: Thanks for the feed back Archer! It didn't work however? I tried stuffing it in loop and didn't work for me either...

Comment: You don't need to do anything to that.  I'll add the document ready tags so it's complete then just copy and paste it.

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle demo.  The only difference is that the demo uses a class, instead of ids.

Comment: No problem mate.  I just though the class method is earier, and if you use common javascript then it's just one block of code for all pages.  Glad to help :)

Comment: Just thought I would share that I'm using this approach in the Wordpress post field. Instead of having to write out a list, this approach works well if you need to create the list on the fly. I can use <div class="myclass"> one*two*three*four* </div>

Answer (score 2):

To ease with reusability, try making the processing logic into a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.listFromText = function() {
        var $source = this;
        var text = this.text();
        var delimiter = "*";

        $source.html("<ul></ul>");

        $.each(text.split(delimiter), function (k, v) {
            $("ul", $source).append('<li>' + '<a>' + v + '</a>' +  '</li>');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#d0").listFromText();
$("#d1").listFromText();
$("#d2").listFromText();
```

This may be overkill if only required for a single page, but handy if to be used consistently accross a project.

Comment: Yeah, I have at least 8pages that are using this approach. Thanks again for the quick feedback!!

Comment: +1, Really like this approach. Made some small improvents to reduce the amount of DOM updates and to maintain chainability though; http://jsfiddle.net/2MjZE/

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.textTolist = function() {
        var textArr = $(this).text().split('*'),
        target = $(this).empty().append('<ul></ul>');
        for (var i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
            $('ul', target).append('<li><a>' + textArr[i] + '</a></li>');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#d0, #d1, #d2').each(function() {
    $(this).textTolist();
});
```